# Cannot install Pymongo on Pythonista3 for iPad due to TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pythonista

I've tried using StaSH in order to install Pymongo but it fails due to the setup.py file erroring. I've even tried installing Pymongo from source by running the setup.py file, but both methods give me the following error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'OmniClass'
```

The commands I ran in StaSH:

```
$ pip install pymongo
$ python3 -m pymongo
ImportError: No module named bson
```

It gives me an error that says module BSON is not found, I have been advised not to install the Bson module from Pypy as it's completely different. No, I'm not having name clashes (the epoch error), I haven't installed Bson.

My question: Can anyone advise any steps I can take to get Pymongo working via installing it from StaSH or from source.

Comment: The specifc line erroring is: `_use_env_markers = tuple(map(int, _setuptools_version.split('.')[:2])) > (20, 9)`

Comment: Try rephrasing this as a question and also provide the exact steps that you took and/or shell commands you entered.

Comment: There we go, I've updated my post.

Comment: does `pip3 install pymongo` work?

Comment: it's pip in stash and well yes I have, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Both the ”OmniClass” in the error and the 7.1% share of C in the github project point to this not really being a pure Python implementation, and thus not installable on Pythonista.